# EventListener not working on custom component in Java

Tags: java, events, awt

I'm trying to draw a shape that is responsive to mouse events,
I thought of extending awt.component that can be registered to event listeners but it ain't working, although it compiles with no errors.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Ball extends Component{
    public Ball(){
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                // Some event to be triggered
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's an example I'm testing on applet using appletviewer (for learning purpose):

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends Applet{
    Ball ball;

    public void init(){
        ball = new Ball();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        ball.paint(g);
    }
}


class Ball extends Component{
    int x, y;

    public Ball(){
        x = y = 50;
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                x += 50;
                y += 50;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.fillOval(x, y, 25, 25);
        }
}
```

It only works when the event listener is assigned to the applet as in the following code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends Applet{
    Ball ball;

    public void init(){
        ball = new Ball();

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                ball.x += 50;
                ball.y += 50;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        ball.paint(g);
    }
}

class Ball extends Component{
    int x, y;
    public Ball(){
        x = y = 50;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.fillOval(x, y, 25, 25);
        }

}
```

Comment: it works on my machine, can you post a working example to see how you are using Ball maybe that could help in solving your problem

Comment: @JRowan I've updated with the a simple example i'm testing

Comment: I was running as a Java Application not a Java Applet, I'm not to sure about applets but maybe that's how the mouse listener is supposed to be implemented in the Applet class, I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `repaint` method, when called in `Ball`, only repaints the `Ball` object, and not the applet screen.

When you add the method in the applet, it repaints the applet screen.

So, you yourself have solved this problem.... You know the answer! I added this answer just for explanation.

Or, you would need to add `repaint` in both, in `Ball` to change the position, and in the applet to repaint it.